# Excel VBA rest API connection to SuiteCRM

Tags: excel, vba, rest, api, suitecrm

I have an Excel file that I am trying to connect to SuiteCRM.  The file already connects to several other applications via REST via msxml2.serverxmlhttp but I can not figure this one out.

I have tried a hundred different configurations but I always get in return either a description of rest.php, an invalid logon error or a bad data passed error, never a session ID.

I have found almost nothing online between VBA and SuiteCRM but this works with other rest APIs so I am hoping I can get it to work with SuiteCRM as well.  I think the login credentials are a big part of the problem but my username and password for now are just "admin" and "s".  I have converted the password to an MD5 has (I tried 2 different methods and got 2 different hashes but neither worked).

The error description is so vague I can't seem to narrow down the problem to figure it out.  Any help would be appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
Function SuiteCRMInitialRequest() As String
Dim oXH As Object
Dim url As String
    url = "http://192.168.1.1/suitecrm/service/v4_1/rest.php?"
    Set oXH = CreateObject("msxml2.serverxmlhttp")
    With oXH
        .Open "POST", url, False
        .SetRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"
        .SetRequestHeader "Accept", "application/json"
        .SetRequestHeader "Host", "192.168.1.1"
        .SetRequestHeader "Content-Length", "180"
        .SetRequestHeader "Expect", "100-continue"
        .SetRequestHeader "Connection", "Keep-Alive"
        .SetRequestHeader "method", "login"
        .SetRequestHeader "input_type", "JSON"
        .SetRequestHeader "response_type", "JSON"
        .Send (SuiteCRMJSONBuild4)
        SuiteCRMInitialRequest = .GetAllResponseHeaders
    End With
    Set oXH = Nothing
End Function

Function SuiteCRMJSONBuild4() As String
Dim strOut As String
        strOut = "{"
        strOut = strOut & """user_auth"":"
        strOut = strOut & "{"
        strOut = strOut & """user_name"":" & """" & "admin" & """" & ","
        'strOut = strOut & """password"":" & """" & SHA1HASH("s") & """" & ","
        strOut = strOut & """password"":" & """" & "03c7c0ace395d80182db07ae2c30f034" & """" & ","
        strOut = strOut & """version"":" & """" & "1" & """" & ""
        strOut = strOut & "},"
        strOut = strOut & """application_name"":" & """" & "test" & """" & ","
        strOut = strOut & """name_value_list"":[]" & ""
        strOut = strOut & "}"
ExitProc:
    SuiteCRMJSONBuild4 = strOut
    Debug.Print strOut
    Exit Function
End Function
```

the code above produces:
Bad data passed in; [Return to Home](http://192.168.1.31/suitecrm)
the return to home links to 192.168.1.31.  I have no idea where that ip comes from but it isn't the server address of suitecrm.  Don't know if that's part of my problem or something unrelated.

the json string created is:
{"user_auth":{"user_name":"admin","password":"03c7c0ace395d80182db07ae2c30f034","version":"1"},"application_name":"test","name_value_list":[]}

Comment: Please include error descriptions against the code that generated it

Answer (score 0):

Ugh.  I figured it out (by accident).  Anybody else trying to use VBA might find this helpful since there was very little I was able to find online.  This ended up working (posting method, input_type and response_type as a string instead of in the header).  Now I will have to see if I can get a follow-up request working.  Thanks a lot for looking at this.

```
Function SuiteCRMInitialRequest2() As String
Dim oXH As Object
Dim url As String
Dim strAll As String
    url = "http://192.168.1.1/suitecrm/service/v4_1/rest.php?"
    Set oXH = CreateObject("msxml2.serverxmlhttp")
    With oXH
        .Open "POST", url, False
        .SetRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"
        .SetRequestHeader "Accept", "application/json"
        .SetRequestHeader "Host", "192.168.1.1"
        .SetRequestHeader "Content-Length", "180"
        .SetRequestHeader "Expect", "100-continue"
        .SetRequestHeader "Connection", "Keep-Alive"
        strAll = "method=login&input_type=JSON&response_type=JSON&rest_data=" & SuiteCRMJSONBuild4
        .Send (strAll)
        SuiteCRMInitialRequest2 = .GetAllResponseHeaders
    End With
    Set oXH = Nothing
End Function
```